# Message: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php

I am getting below error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Parsing Error
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW
>
> Filename: controllers/Welcome.php
>
> Line Number: 15
>
> Backtrace:

**my code is**

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');    
    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct(){ 
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('HotelModel');
        }    
        public function index(){    
            $hotData = $this->HotelModel->getAllHotelList();
            $cityData = $this->HotelModel->getAllHotelCity(); 
            $this->load->view('public/index',('hotData' => $hotData,'cityData' => $cityData));
        }
    }
?>
```

I am not able to find my mistake.

Comment: `,('hotData' => $hotData,'cityData' => $cityData)` as this is an array - it should be in [] brackets.

Comment: `$this->load->view('public/index',array('hotData' => $hotData,'cityData' => $cityData));` or  `$this->load->view('public/index',['hotData' => $hotData,'cityData' => $cityData]);`

Comment: sorry if i add [ ] i am getting below error;

Comment: Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '['

Filename: controllers/Welcome.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

Comment: Try the other version posted by Noman.